# Does a PolyLineZ feature (and shapefile) have to have M values?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, julia

I'm having an interoperability issue between QGIS and [Shapefile.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Shapefile.jl) that revealed some of my confusion about shapefiles.

I draped a vector layer with topographic information using QGIS, putting the topography into the new layer's Z vector and creating a PolyLineZ layer. I assumed that the new layer didn't need to have M values in addition to the Z values. But, [Shapefile.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGeo/Shapefile.jl) expects M values and Z values for a PolyLineZ layer and the [shapefile definition](https://www.esri.com/Library/Whitepapers/Pdfs/Shapefile.pdf) (page 17 of the pdf) indicates that any PolyLineZ has an M vector.

Why does a PolyLineZ always need an M vector?

Comment: Page 18 has a note that indicates Ms are ***optional*** in a PolyLineZ record (Z's are NOT optional in a PolyLineM)

Comment: This probably does not answer your question but these may be interesting https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2124 https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2033 and the thread https://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg25896.html.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. It seems like whether different software respects optional M values in PolyLineZ layers is variable.

Comment: Do you happen to know how shapefiles with optional M values are written? Do they have null M values or are the M values totally omitted?

Comment: Either or according to this mail by Mike Toews from the thread above https://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg25883.html